# DataSet MSDataSetGenerator Not Working in .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ado.net

I'm converting a .NET Framework 4.6.1 Library to .NET Core 2.1.2.  The old data access library contains a DataSet.  I've created a new Visual Studio project from the Class Library (.NET Core) template and added a DataSet.  The Project does not group the DataSet.xsc and DataSet.xss files under the DataSet.xsd.  Also, the Custom Tool MSDataSetGenerator does not generate the DataSet.Designer.cs file.

I found the problem posted on the Developer Community Site, see [DataSet designer error in .net standard 2.0 library](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/63351/dataset-designer.html).

Does anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Still having the same problem in VS 2017 15.5.7, System.Data.Common 4.3 and System.Data.SqlClient 4.4.2. Also not possible to have a column of type Guid. Visual designer refuses to reopen file.